# Create new column based on whether date and time at which a species occurs is between other dates, over multiple time periods

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, write.table

I have a dataframe (df1) with multiple rows species, and the date-time event at which that species occurs that looks like this:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(sample(seq(from=as.POSIXct("2023-07-01 00:00"), 
            to=as.POSIXct("2023-07-01 00:20"), by="sec"), 21))
df1
colnames(df1) <- c('day.hour.df1') #rename column of df2
df1$Species <- c("a", "b", "b", "a", "c", "NA", "a", "a", "c", "b", "b", 
                 "c", "c", "NA", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "NA", "b") 
                 # add species column
names(df1)
```

And I have a second dataframe (df2) that, as columns, contains a start (as day and time) (START.df2) an end (END.df2), and species (here "a"). the second dataframe looks like follows:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(seq(from=as.POSIXct("2023-07-01 00:00:00"), 
                     to=as.POSIXct("2023-07-01 00:20:00"), by="min"))
df2
df2$time2 <- (seq(from=as.POSIXct("2023-07-01 00:00:59"), 
              to=as.POSIXct("2023-07-01 00:20:59"), by="min"))
names(df1)
df2$species <- (c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 
                  'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'))
df2

colnames(df1) <- c('START.df2', 'END.df2', 'Species')
```

I want to add to the second dataframe (df2) a new column called "occurrence_a", where, if the species "a" contained in df1 occurs at a day_time (day.hour.df1) in between START (START.df2) and END (END.df2), of dataframe 2 (df2), it gives a 1, otherwise, it gives 0.

I tried this but without success:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% left_join(df1, by = "Species") %>% 
  mutate( = between(day.hour.df2, START.df1, END.df1)) %>% 
  group_by(species, day.hour.df1) %>% 
  summarise(OCCURRENCEa = any(OCCURRENCEa))
df2
```

Comment: please provide a sample output. The example data can be much smaller too. I believe you can reproduce the issues with 20 data points or less.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have changed my question according to your request.

Comment: NEVER share screenshots of the data. Always share data as code we can paste into our consoles and manipulate

Comment: well, all the needed data are in the codes I provided above, the screenshot is ONLY an example of what I would like to get as an output (as you requested). If I knew how to get this done, I wouldn't have had any needs to ask this question here... don't you think?

Comment: no, you are wrong. Minimal reprexes are usually small and self-contained. Unless the desired output can be easily understood (not the case in this question), it is advisable to include it. Since these are small datasets, we can always hard code it.

Comment: I am voting to close this question down as "needing more details/clarity".

Comment: well, go ahead. I have already made huge changes so if you don't get those I don't know what to say more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what output you want, but I think this should be close at least:

```
left_join(df2, df1, join_by(Species, between(y$day.hour.df1, x$START.df2, x$END.df2))) %>% 
  group_by(Species, START.df2, END.df2) %>% 
  summarise(
    OCCURRENCE = any(!is.na(day.hour.df1)) %>% as.numeric(), 
    .groups = 'drop'
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Species, values_from = OCCURRENCE, names_prefix = 'OCCURRENCE')
```

You don't really need the pivotting and such for this example, but I am assuming you have multiple species in your real data and want different columns for those.

Comment: thanks so much, this is exactly what I needed in this specific case. I really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Best of luck with your great tits!